# Graphic card drivers

Tags: 13.04, drivers, ati, intel

I installed Ubuntu on my HP ProBook 4740s. When I tried to install new graphic card drivers, Unity doesn't start, or worse, I get the low graphic mode(and the screen freezes). I have tried installing the drivers directly from the manufacturer and changing the drivers in the Additional Hardware Driver menu from the default setting.

I would rather install them directly from the manufacturer.

Perhaps this is helpful:

Output of `lspci | grep VG`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Thames [Radeon 7550M/7570M/7650M]
```

Comment: Can you disable the integrated Intel GPU in the BIOS?

Comment: Not really an option because mostly I want to use the Intel GPU because it consumes less power and use the AMD one only when I need to.And I dont want to reboot always my computer to do that.For that I need the drivers and AMD Catalyst.

Comment: Well, I am not entirely sure, but I think Catalyst does not support  multi GPU setup.